# jQuery/Javascript - detect changes in select option when val is change in browsers console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that triggers when the select option is changed, however when the value is changed in browsers console it will not detect the change event.

```
$("#additional_myfield3").on('change', function(){
// recalculation of shipping cost
});
```

UPDATE
This is in WooCommerce, changes in select option will update the shipping cost. By default shipping is $0, but when changed it will recalculate and will range from $5-$10.

- Changing value in console

```
jQuery('select#additional_myfield3').val('Location 1');
```

The problem is when option is changed via console, it will not update the shipping cost. In backend the TEAM is changed to "Location 1" but the shipping cost is still 0, when it should be $5.

Comment: have you used console.like: `$("#additional_myfield3").val("have you tried this?").trigger("change")`? or using JS `$0.value = "have you tried this?"` and `$0.change()` where `$0` is the currently highlighted "inspect element" reference of dev tools.

Comment: Also, explore: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and  [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) - since I have not the slightest idea what are you after.

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan, I updated my post. sorry for not giving the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initialize this after the page has loaded, as in

```
window.onload = function() {
  $("#additional_myfield3").on('change', function(){
     alert('changed');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#additional_myfield3").on('change', function() {
  alert('changed');
});


//on console should trigger change
$("#additional_myfield3").val("2").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- on input should trigger change -->
<select id="additional_myfield3">
  <option value="1">1
    <option value="2">2
</select>
```